# Mobile changePage Post Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I've read through the jQuery Mobile documentation on `$.mobile.changePage()`
although I'm still stuck on knowing how to retrieve the posted data.

I have the code:

```
$.mobile.changePage( "videoplayer.asp", {
            type: "post", 
            data: data
        });
```

On the `videoplayer.asp` page I have some more jQuery that runs to setup a video player although I can't seem to access the posted data.

I've tried a few solutions, which are really just guesses:

```
$.get(data)
$.post(data)
data by itself
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the POST data from the Javascript on videoplayer.asp, you can only access POST-data on the server (in your case in the asp code).

If you want to pass an parameter (say VideoId) to the javascript on videoplayer.asp I would recommend that you set it in the querystring of the URL.

Something like:

```
var videoId = 1000;
$.mobile.changePage("videoplayer.asp?videoId=" + videoId);
```

That way you can read it with your Javascript.

[You can read more how to get query string values with Javascript here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use some `.asp` code to add the necessary `POST` data to your JavaScript.

Sorry I don't have much experience with `.asp` but here is how to do it in `PHP`:

```
<script>
var post_data = <?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>;
</script>
```

This will save the `POST` data to a JavaScript object.

You can access `GET` variables in JavaScript though with the `location.search` property.